# Could someone add a way to retrieve an error from a state machine?

Tags: spring-statemachine

Like the title says. There are methods for setting (setStateMachineError) and checking for (hasStateMachineError) errors, but there is no way to retrieve the actual Exception from the state machine. One workaround is to add the Exception to the extended state, but it just seems logic that there would be another way to easily retrieve it. I'm not sure this is the right place for feature requests, please point me to the right direction if it's not.